# 301 redirect to new URL from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento

Needs a favour from your side, I have added following rule in htaccess files not sure why it is not executing can you check and let us know if any issue

```
Redirect 301 /product/rose-elliot%E2%80%99s-__060727.aspx http://www.website.co.uk/ahhgh.html

Redirect 301 /abc/%20/index.php/customer/account/login/ https://www.website.co.uk/customer/account/login/
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us the actual rule...

Answer (score 1):

URI's get decoded before being sent through the URL-file-mapping processing pipeline. So you need to unescape the `%`'s:

```
Redirect 301 "/product/abcd.aspx" http://www.website.co.uk/abcd.html

Redirect 301 "/abcd/ /index.php/customer/account/login/" https://www.website.co.uk/customer/account/login/
```

You'll need to make sure you're using a text editor that supports unicode.